# Pagination to return total count and total pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagination, entity-framework-core

### Problem

I am creating an API and apply filter to it to paginate on the query. when send response now I need to send Totalcount and TotalPages with the result. by this method Now I am getting this kind of response in case of success

### result

```
{
  "error": "string",
  "success": "string",
  "statusCode": 0,
  "result": {
      [ {object}, ]
   }
}
```

Now I need this result instead of above result How can I achieve this need some good suggestion.

### Needed result

```
{
  "error": "string",
  "success": "string",
  "statusCode": 0,
  "result": {
      "TotalPages":"50",
      "TotalCount":"908945",
      "model":[ {object},]
   }
}
```

### interface

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    int PageIndex { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
    int TotalCount { get; }
    int TotalPages { get; }
    bool HasPreviousPage { get; }
    bool HasNextPage { get; }
}
```

### PageList Class

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
{

    public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        int total = source.Count();
        this.TotalCount = total;
        this.TotalPages = total / pageSize;

        if (total % pageSize > 0)
            TotalPages++;

        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = pageIndex;
        this.AddRange(source.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
    }


    public PagedList(IList<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        TotalCount = source.Count();
        TotalPages = TotalCount / pageSize;

        if (TotalCount % pageSize > 0)
            TotalPages++;

        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = pageIndex;
        this.AddRange(source.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
    }


    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalCount)
    {
        TotalCount = totalCount;
        TotalPages = TotalCount / pageSize;

        if (TotalCount % pageSize > 0)
            TotalPages++;

        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = pageIndex;
        this.AddRange(source);
    }

    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get { return (PageIndex > 0); }
    }
    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get { return (PageIndex + 1 < TotalPages); }
    }
}
```

### Service

```
public IPagedList<Model> SomeMethod(int id, int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = int.MaxValue)
{
    var query = //select query

    var reslt= new PagedList<Model>(query, pageIndex, pageSize);
    return reslt;


}
```

### API

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ApiResponse GetApi([FromRoute] int id, int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = int.MaxValue)
{
    if (id == 0)
        return new ApiResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, error: "id must be provided");


    var result = someMethod(id, pageIndex, pageSize);
    return new ApiResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, result, "success");
}
```

### ApiResponse

```
public class ApiResponse
{

    public ApiResponse(int statusCode, object result = null, string success = "", string error = "")
    {
        Error = error;
        Success = success;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Result = result;      
    }

    public string Error { get; set; }
    public string Success { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public Object Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you set the paging values in the HTTP header.  Keep the data in the model and separate the paging data.  Good article on this is http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/paging-in-aspnet-webapi-http-headers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Just do this and my code woks as I expected

```
var TotalCount =result.TotalCount
var TotalPages =result.TotalPages
//after getting these value pass in the result
return new ApiResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, result: new {result : result, totalCount : TotalCount, totalPages : TotalPages}, "success");
```

because the properties of total pages and total count already in the IPagedList interface and it inherited in PagedList

Comment: 2 small issues.  1) ='s not :'s 2) result property should be model.  new { model = result, totalCount = TotalCount, totalPages = totalPages }

Comment: and 'result' would be 'data' in the response object unless you rename ApiResponse.Data to ApiResponse.Result
`{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "data": {
        "model": [
            {
                "myProperty": "Hello World"
            }
        ],
        "totalCount": 908945,
        "totalPages": 50
    },
    "success": "success",
    "error": null
}`

Comment: Answering your own questions every time? Suppose it's one way to "build your rep".

Comment: Answering your own questions is completely fine. Even SO suggests this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/